# how to send scheduled notification to flutter app through firebase cloud messaging

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have  integrated firebase cloud messaging and trying to remind notification  the users when the appointments time before 5 min. but only shows where https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send api has requested

I also tried with token and subscribing topic

but how to schedule the notification

```
{
   "to": "/topics/installers",
  "notification": {
    "title": "notification title",
    "body": "notification body",
    "isScheduled" : "true",
    "scheduledTime" : "2023-01-12 14:32:00"
  }
}
```

Comment: How does your app know the time of the appointment. Do you use a database to store this?

Comment: yes, From database i will store and get data through api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way to send scheduled push notifications is for a cloud function or a function on your server to read the database and send a message at the appropriate time.

With appointments, that would mean running the function every minute or so which may have cost implications.

You could also look at https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications package but that needs the app to be active or running in the background. Some devices will not allow prolonged background activity for apps.

Comment: Is there way to read my database (not in firebase's real-time or cloud firestore database) through api call  response data in firebase cloud function and then call fcm api  to send notification, can write & run function like this firebase cloud function index.js file

Comment: I've only worked with fcm as part of the firebase suite of products but I am pretty sure you could drive this from a database on your server. Someone else would need to tell you how, though.

Comment: Maybe an article like this can help https://blog.logrocket.com/implement-in-app-notifications-nest-js-mysql-firebase/

Comment: Thank you , any other way like migrating  fcm legacy http to http v1  will add parameter `sent_time` in the send request   fcm  api  then scheduling  to certain time and get notification appropriate time

Comment: Have to pass on that question. Hopefully someone else can help more.

Comment: ok,  i will put the question related this, thank you